# pywinauto hangs on app with List with 448 entries

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

This is a fairly simple question. I have a program that want to automate (Darwinex MT4) and I have a problem with pywinauto. When I use pywinauto to locate some items, it works. No problems. But when a long list is populated by the program, pywinauto does not work anymore. And it always ends up with:

```
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError
```

Note that If I run the EXACT SAME SCRIPT (no changes made) in the same program, but in another pane view (where the list is not displayed), it works ok.

```
import ctypes
import re
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import findwindows, Application
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
from pywinauto.win32structures import RECT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wins = findwindows.find_windows(title_re=".*Darwinex")
    
    Timings.window_find_timeout = 300
    
    if len(wins) <= 0:
        raise Exception("Darwinex no está activo, tío.")
    else:
        app: Application = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia", allow_magic_lookup=False)
        
        app.connect(title_re=r".*Darwinex", control_type="Window")
        
        print('app-> ', app.top_window().child_window(title='Probador', top_level_only=True).dump_tree(), flush=True)
```

And I am not trying to access an element that is not available because I changed the view or something, because if I inspect with inspect.exe, the tree remains the same, only the new list is added, and then no matter what I do works. I tried to up the timings to 300, and not to use magic name resolution. Nothing works.

I suspect there is a problem with loads of entries.

[image: When in this view, it works (and the Resultados view is, indeed, in memory, but not graphically displayed]

[image: When in this view, it doesn't work]